# Fire and forget NSOperation

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation

If I add a `NSOperation` to `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` and don't really care about the result, can I be sure that it will run even though the object that added it to the queue goes out of scope?

The operation performs a HTTP request, but even if it fails I don't want to inform the user about the error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the operation queue will retain the operation.